# How to handle touch events and click-events of a slidingUpPanelLayout and the elements inside of it

Tags: android, android-sliding, android-imagebutton

in my app I created a SlidingUpPanelLayout with inside a gridview of imagebuttons. The slidinguppanel is half hidden and when you swipe it up it becomes full visibile, when you swipe it down it becomes half hidden.
When you tap on an imagebutton, it works correctly.
I have a "bug" that I need to solve, when you swipe it up (or down) while touching the area between image buttons the sliding panel it works correctly, but if you do the same thing in a area near or on the imagebuttons, the sliding panel doesn't move.

this is my code:

setting the adapter at the gridview and the ontouchlistener

```
gridView.setAdapter(new GridServicesAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.grid_view_services_row, actions.getActions()));

gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Here I override the ongloballayout for using the SlidingUpPanelLayout

```
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    SlidingUpPanelLayout root = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) getView()
            .findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
    if (slidingPanelHeight == null) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        slidingPanelHeight = root.getHeight()
                - root.findViewById(R.id.indicator).getHeight()
                - (int) (display.getWidth() * 9. / 16);
    }
    root.setPanelHeight(slidingPanelHeight);
    root.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
}
```

I used this library https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel .

What I'd like to emulate is the behavior of a lot of apps, the google-play  app is a perfect example. While you are on the homepage you can scroll the page touching the area that you want, but if you tap on an icon you can go to the page that you tapped. 
Could you please help me? :-)
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the event is registered by the GridView instead of your custom layout, since you're putting a scrollable element inside a scrollable element. Exactly how does this differ from a regular GridView anyway? Animations?

Comment: Yes exactly the animation of this library is cooler than a simple gridview and it is the graphic designer's choice "if u know what I mean" =)

Comment: Unfortunately I do know what you mean all too well, but you can't put a scrollable element in another scrollable that scrolls in the same direction and expect it to work properly. I'd change the gridview to something that doesn't scroll to see if that works, then give every icon its own clicklistener.